# Docker pull gives expected HTTP 206 from byte range request

Tags: docker, proget, docker-pull

I am having trouble pulling docker images from our on-site proget server.  This had been working, but I've been away from it for about 2 months.

I run:
docker pull proget/docker/myimage

A few layers complete (pull complete), but the biggest gives 'expected HTTP 206 from byte range request'.

This happens with several images.
How can I tell what this layer is?  Maybe I can get it from the public server.

```
I am running Linux containers on a Windows 10 box.
PS H:\> docker --version
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
```

Here is the output of my docker pull command:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from docker/myimage
d519e2592276: Already exists
d22d2dfcfa9c: Already exists
b3afe92c540b: Already exists
9abe5f2bbd53: Already exists
65becf0a3765: Already exists
9c36e7f174ec: Retrying in 1 second
9475aaec4d08: Download complete
6500e30cdfd9: Download complete
expected HTTP 206 from byte range request
```

I am using ProGet Version 5.3.18 (Build 14), and I am not behind a proxy.

Comment: Can you please show us the output from the `docker pull` command, include the version of ProGet, and tell us about whether the ProGet server is behind a proxy ?

Comment: @TheQueenIsDead, I have this same problem. I tried to pull [`raabf/latex-versions:latest`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/raabf/latex-versions/latest/images/sha256-bc8ac8df7765b2946b9bd37d4eb91e8cb8a2b5d0dfc7676db459a1cd9bfcab6f?context=explore). It has 1.89GB. I ran the command `docker pull [censored-bank-address]/raabf/latex-versions`. I have set correctly the bank proxy. I added `"max-concurrent-downloads": 1`. But totally unsucessful.

Comment: Hi @GustavoReis were you able to get this working ? I'm having the same problem too in Macbook pro in Apple M1 Processor.

Comment: @sevvalai, it turned the company limited the image size. You have to create several tags, from `minimal` to `full`. Firstly, I pull the `minimal` tag, the basic `texlive` tag and finally the `full` tag. On my personal computer, there was not an image size limit.

Comment: Thanks, we don't have image size constraint, because they same image is getting downloaded without any issues in an intel I7 macbook, its the Apple M1 processor which is not working.