# I am unable to pull a Docker image bigger than 1GB due to two errors `Retrying in 1 second` and `expected HTTP 206 from byte range request`

Tags: docker, docker-pull, docker-proxy

I have this same problem referred to the question [Docker pull gives expected HTTP 206 from byte range request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68658374/docker-pull-gives-expected-http-206-from-byte-range-request).

I tried to pull [`raabf/latex-versions:latest`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/raabf/latex-versions/latest/images/sha256-bc8ac8df7765b2946b9bd37d4eb91e8cb8a2b5d0dfc7676db459a1cd9bfcab6f?context=explore). It has 1.89GB. I ran the command `docker pull [censored-company-address]/raabf/latex-versions`. I have set correctly the company proxies. I added `"max-concurrent-downloads": 1`. But totally unsuccessful because of errors `Retrying in 1 second` and `expected HTTP 206 from byte range request`.

Only less than 1GB, I am able to pull any Docker image.

Comment: That matches practical experiences I've had in the past.  Try restructuring your Dockerfile to have smaller layers, or to use multi-stage builds to keep build tools out of the final image.  Very large data files may also need to be distributed separately from the image, though that should be a last resort.